# How to convert text to bitmap of text *Not Binary*

Tags: python, text, bitmap, converters

I'm trying to convert text into bitmap, but not bitmap of the binary but the text itself.

E.g for the text "SCIENCE" the picture should be the result. Has this been done before? I can't find anything on it...

[image: SCIENCE]

The solution I found:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

img = Image.new('L', (100, 10))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((1,1), "SCIENCE",255)
img.save('pil_text.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a drawing library to do that, such as `PIL` - here is a [reference](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html) which also includes drawing text on an image. Make sure to use [`PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.textsize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.textsize) to measure the size of the text, then create an image of that size, and then draw the text.

Comment: Thanks I got it working with this!